# Loop through JSON objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, getjson

I have a JSON structure like this in my JavaScript code

```
[{"id":10,"latitude":"49","longitude":"2","altitude":"construction","name":"sjiajnjdksaa","description":"jfis","urlidle":"asd","urlselected":"asd"},
    {"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"},

    {"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"},

    {"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"},

    {"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"},

    {"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"},

    {"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"}]
```

This is obtained from a `$.getJSON(serverUrl, function(data)` method like the follows.

```
var serverUrl = https://demo.blah.fgh/return.php?lat=20;
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(serverUrl, function(data) {
console.log(jqxhr.responseText);
```

However, I need to iterate through each one of them and get each row into an object like the follows

```
//Loop Starts

var singlePoi = {
                "id": poiData[i].id,
                "latitude": parseFloat(poiData[i].latitude),
                "longitude": parseFloat(poiData[i].longitude),
                "altitude": parseFloat(poiData[i].altitude),
                "title": poiData[i].name,
                "description": poiData[i].description,
                "urlidle": poiData[i].urlidle,
                "urlselected": poiData[i].urlselected

            };
// Now do operations with singlePoi
//Loop ends
```

Comment: do you want to put each array object into separate Object. You can, but think about numbers of Object you need to take care after. And also how you will name these object?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery,

```
$.each(pioData, function(i, v) {
        v.latitude = parseFloat(v.latitude);
        ...
        ...
        ...

});
```

Because essentially, what you are doing to the array of objects is changing each attribute's value type. When you are done iterating, you can just use `pioData` again, modified to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this classical javascript forEach

lets your Json structure is

```
var data=[{"id":10,"latitude":"49","longitude":"2","altitude":"construction","name":"sjiajnjdksaa","description":"jfis","urlidle":"asd","urlselected":"asd"},
{"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"},

{"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"},

{"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"},

{"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"},

{"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"},

{"id":10,"latitude":"22","longitude":"10","altitude":"asd","name":"zxcvbnmmmkk","description":"kk","urlidle":"qwerty","urlselected":"qwerty"}];

//Loop Starts
    data.forEach(function(poiData){
var singlePoi = {
                "id": poiData.id,
                "latitude": parseFloat(poiData.latitude),
                "longitude": parseFloat(poiData.longitude),
                "altitude": parseFloat(poiData.altitude),
                "title": poiData.name,
                "description": poiData.description,
                "urlidle": poiData.urlidle,
                "urlselected": poiData.urlselected

            };
// Now do operations with singlePoi
});
//Loop ends
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to iterate through the return and format the objects, you can do something like this:

```
function formatReturn(data) {
  var formattedData = [];
  data.forEach( function(poiData) {
    formattedData.push(
      {
        "id": poiData.id,
        "latitude": parseFloat(poiData.latitude),
        "longitude": parseFloat(poiData.longitude),
        "altitude": parseFloat(poiData.altitude),
        "title": poiData.name,
        "description": poiData.description,
        "urlidle": poiData.urlidle,
        "urlselected": poiData.urlselected
      }
    );
  });
  console.log(formattedData);
}
```

Note that in this case you will still have an array of objects, but the latitude, longitude, and altitude attributes will have parseFloat applied to them.

If you are looking to store all of the rows as attributes in an object, you could do something like this:

```
function formatReturn(data) {
  var formattedData = {};
  data.forEach( function(poiData,index) {
    formattedData["singlePoi_"+index] =
      {
      "id": poiData.id,
      "latitude": parseFloat(poiData.latitude),
      "longitude": parseFloat(poiData.longitude),
      "altitude": parseFloat(poiData.altitude),
      "title": poiData.name,
      "description": poiData.description,
      "urlidle": poiData.urlidle,
      "urlselected": poiData.urlselected
    };
  }
  console.log(formattedData);
}
```

The above will store each item in the JSON return as a new attribute of the formattedData object.